Automate actions on personal account on Telegram
Bots are limited in permissions to personal accounts in Telegram (e.g. bot can be added to a group by admin only but any personal account can be added to the group freely). So bot API is not suitable.
Is there a way to automate personal account in Telegram?
I'm not going to send any messages, only reading messages. I think it's aligned with Telegram terms & services.

I can use Telegram API (the one to create alternative Telegram clients) like this one https://docs.pyrogram.org/ for my needs.
Looks like such things are called userbots.
